# Using the String(bytes[]) constructor for an InputStream

Tags: java, android

I'm wondering **what the objections are** to using what I'll call the 'String constructor method' to convert an `InputStream` into a String.

Edit: added emphasis. In particular, I'm wondering why we have to mess with Streams and Buffers and Scanners and whatnot when this method seems to work fine.

```
private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        return new String(buffer, 0, in.read(buffer));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Error reading input stream!");
        return "";
    }
}
```

I've seen [this other helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string) and tried the methods I could:

- Method 1, Apache commons, is a no-go, since I can't use and don't want libraries right now.
- Method 2, The `Scanner` one, looks promising, but then you'd have to be able to set delimiters in the stream, which isn't always possible, right? E.g. right now I'm using an InputStream from a web API.
- Method 3, the `InputStreamReader` in the `slurp` function, didn't work either - it gives me a bunch of numbers, where I'm sending a string with all types of characters, so I may be messing something up in my encoding.

But after many Google searches, I finally found the String constructor method, which is the only one that works for me.

From comments on the thread I linked, I know there are issues with encoding in the method I'm using. I've been coding for a while now and know what encodings are and why they're around. But I still lack any knowledge about what kinds of encodings are used where, and how to detect and handle them. Any resources/help on that topic would also be very appreciated!

Comment: The `InputStream` is not required to read all the bytes, so depending on what you are trying to achieve, it may not be possible like this.

Comment: As a general rule, just use UTF-8.  Always.  No exceptions.  Do it.

Comment: You have the option to slurp all bytes into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then try and decode all the bytes using a `CharsetDecoder`. If successful, the `CharBuffer`'s `.toString()` method will be your string. Note that using a `CharsetDecoder` configured the "ass tight" way, you can detect errors: by default the string constructor _replaces_ unmappable byte sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using only standard libraries:

- use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and copy all the bytes you receive in it;
- wrap this `ByteArrayOutputStream`'s bytes into a `ByteBuffer`;
- use a `CharsetDecoder` to decode the `ByteBuffer` into a `CharBuffer`;
- `.toString()` the `CharBuffer` after rewinding it.

Code (note: doesn't handle closing the input):

```
// Step 1: read all the bytes
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];

int count;

while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    out.write(buf, 0, count);

// Step 2: wrap the array
final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(out.toByteArray());

// Step 3: decode
final CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()
    .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);

final CharBuffer charBuffer = decoder.decode(byteBuffer);

charBuffer.flip();
return charBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! I'm a little unfamiliar with Streams and Buffers, though, so I can't see what the advantage of using the ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteBuffer over reading into a Byte[] and using the String constructor is. Does this have to do with what @Sotiros mentioned in his comment on my question?

(Edit: I've added some emphasis in my question)

Comment: That and also the fact that by default the `String` constructor will, as I commented, replace sequences of bytes it cannot map. You can obtain the same behaviour from a `CharsetDecoder` by setting the `CodingErrorAction`s to `REPLACE` (this is what `String` does)

Comment: All right. I've finally run into a problem just as @Sotiros suggested. One last question, though - it would be pretty much equivalent, besides the byte replacement, if I looped and copied every String I got from the InputStream until it returned -1, right? (I think that may have been a method in the link, actually)

Comment: No, it wouldn't be equivalent; say you have a 1024 byte buffer, and at offset 1022 (note: offset starting from 0) you have a 4 byte UTF-8 sequence. You'd botch it if you converted those 1024 bytes immediately. As to ensure a full read, you can use nio's AsynchronousChannel

Comment: Makes sense! `StandardCharsets.UTF-8` isn't available until API level 19, though (Java 7). I'm using ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray and a string constructor for now :)

Comment: `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` may not be available but `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` is ;)